# Why do we need to scale the variables in a Bayesian model?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, pymc

In a Bayesian MMM model using pymc3 the variables are scaled. It is said that scaling helps in improving the efficiency of the MCMC algorithm. Also, it is stated that setting priors for the non-scaled data becomes difficult. What is the intuition behind these claims? Why do we need to scale the variables in the data set for the Bayesian model
?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you *do not need* to scale the variables for a Bayesian model. This may be needed in some, specific, scenarios where you run into numerical issues with the sampling or optimization algorithm that you are using to estimate the parameters. This may be the case when using [variational-inference](/questions/tagged/variational-inference) (e.g. ADVI).

Also, as you mention yourself, in some cases it may be easier to pick priors if the data is scaled, the same as scaling can lead to easier interpretation of parameters in non-Bayesian models (see e.g. [Andrew Galman's blog](https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2009/07/11/when_to_standar/)). If your parameters are easier to interpret, it would be easier to come up with priors for them.